# Docker container setup on Docker free web server

Tags: docker

Simple question, but I haven't found much after Googling.

What I would like to create Linux systems that are based on Docker containers from Docker hub.

If I temporary need a docker-engine this would be OK, once I create a Linux image, but after that docker and docker-engine packages would not be needed.

Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: The first requirement for using docker is to install docker. Period. There's no getting around that.

Comment: That's right. It's not possible. You have control of the server, right? Just install it. If you don't have control of the server, then your question is off-topic here.

Comment: The full control of the web server was my only option. I am in the software industry for 20 years and I learned that almost everything is possible. So I will provide a little more room for some other possible answers.

Comment: It's not possible. Period. Don't bother waiting.

Comment: Excluding the fact that almost every virtue in running docker containers would be gone, the images from Docker Hub rely heavily in two things: pre-compiled binaries and base images. The first is so we don't have to rebuild the entire system everytime we build a image. The second is the base for the installation. I imagine that you could do something like what you're saying by "substituting" the base Docker images with VM images and reapplying every command, but I fail to see the practical side of it.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to have for using docker is all the necessary packages and kernel support for docker command.. If you plan to use docker on a VM without docker.. I'm afraid there is no more to do. 
Are you willing to take a look at other lightweight virtualization technology? Lxd/snap are something that can help you..